# Prove that $|P(\mathbb N) \times P(\mathbb N)| = |(0,1)|.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If $P(\mathbb N)$ denotes the power set of the set of natural numbers, prove that $|P(\mathbb N) \times P(\mathbb N)|=|(0,1)|.$

I have thought of trying to find a bijection from P(N) x P(N) to (0,1).

Alternatively, I could try to use the fact that |P(N)|=|(0,1)| and prove that |P(N) x P(N)|=|P(N)| by finding a bijection from P(N) x P(N) to P(N).

Finally, maybe I could use the fact that |P(N x N)|=|P(N)|=|(0,1)| and try to prove that |P(N) x P(N)|=|P(N x N)| by finding a bijection between P(N) x P(N) and P(N x N).

I am struggling to think up a suitable bijection for any of these options.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you already know that $|P(\mathbb N)|=|(0,1)|?$

Comment: Hint: in general, we have a bijection between $P(A \coprod b)$ and $P(A) \times P(B)$, where $\coprod$ is the disjoint union.

Answer (score 1):

Consider **base three representation** of the real numbers belonging to interval $(0,1)$.

Consider the example :

$$x=.001221110210010210...$$

to this representation, we associate the partition where

- the zeros' and twos' positions denote the first element of $P(\mathbb{N})$,
- the ones' and two's positions denote the second element of $P(\mathbb{N})$.

Remark: the positions begin at $0$.

In the case of our example, it would be:

$$A=\{0,1,3,4,8,10,12,13,14... \} \ \text{and} \\ B=\{2,3,4,5,6,8,9,12,14,15... \}$$

Remarks:

1. Said otherwise, the "zeros", "ones" and "twos" characterize resp. $A \setminus B, \ \ B \setminus A, \ \ A \cap B$
2. There is still some work ; you will have to deal with the non unique base representation of real numbers : for example, in base $3$, number $0.12222...$ with an infinite number or twos is the same as $0.20000...$ with an infinite number of zeros.

Comment: Any comment ?...